# 1TB ext4 Harddrive with 400GB NTFS MBR written by mistake

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, mbr

I was imaging my ext4 1tb storage disk that I had accidentally formatted to NTFS with testdisk and an external usb dock when I had to back out.

Testdisk asked about writing the MBR and I clicked yes.  Bad move. Prior to this I had been copying files from a 400gb using the same dock.  When test disk wrote the MBR it wrote it for the 400GB drive onto the 1TB.  So now I have a 1TB ext4 drive that thinks it is a 400gb NTFS.

I really need the files on this drive (years of research) and it seems that if I can delet the MBR I should be able to at list image the disk (files were all showing up fine in test disk prior to the erroneous MBR write)

How do I erase the MBR without doing any more damage? I am noob with this sort of issue and appreciate all the help I can get.  And I'm more than a little panicked about losing all that data.  Below is part of the testdisk I ran today

```
recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/7452, s_mnt_count=81/37, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 244190646
recover_EXT2: part_size 1953525168
     Linux                60600   0  1 182201  80 63 1953525168 [New Volume]
     EXT4 Large file Sparse superblock Recover, 1000 GB / 931 GiB
This partition ends after the disk limits. (start=973539000, size=1953525168, end=2927064167, disk end=1953536130)
Disk /dev/sdh - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121602 255 63
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...
The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 2041 GB / 1901 GiB)
The following partitions can't be recovered:
     Linux                60597 217 37 182199  43 36 1953525168 [New Volume]
     EXT4 Large file Sparse superblock Recover, 1000 GB / 931 GiB
     Linux                60599  65 11 182200 146 10 1953525168 [New Volume]
     EXT4 Large file Sparse superblock Recover, 1000 GB / 931 GiB
     Linux                60600   0  1 182201  80 63 1953525168 [New Volume]
     EXT4 Large file Sparse superblock Recover, 1000 GB / 931 GiB
     FAT32 LBA            218010 109  3 248252  44  9  485833642
```

Comment: Please format your question so it can actually be read and clarify your question.

Comment: Before you do anything, do a full `dd` from your 1tb drive to a partition on your 3tb drive

Comment: I have fixed the formatting for the question by moving the output of test disk to a code block.

Comment: You might be able to use [SuperGrub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to fix your MBR issue.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I deleted the weird "what" partition using Ubuntu disk utility and this seems to have put me more/less back to where I was before.  Am imaging and will try further recovery methods afterwards. I'll post what works but if there are more suggestions I'm all ears.

Comment: OK, I got my files back. First in disk utility (ubuntu) I deleted the erroneously added [what] partition then I ran fsck /dev/sdh, clicked yes to all the repairs it wanted to make and......voila! Disk mounted and data is back